# How to find folders and files with specific pattern

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file that will write to log all files and folders that contains specific patterns, and with exclude folders, but without success:

```
@ECHO OFF

for /r "%c:\" %%x in (david) do (    
echo "%%x"
findstr /f:exclude.txt /c:"%%x"  > nul || echo.%%x >> c:\david.log
)
goto :eof
```

## exclude file:

C:\$Recycle.Bin\
c:\temp\

Help?

Comment: perhaps `for /f %%a in ('dir /s C:\*david*') do (Echo Stuff...)`

Comment: but i want to exclude spesific paths for ex - c:\$Recycle.bin, c:\temp and etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(exclude is `/g:`; `/f:` is a very different thing - see `for /?`)

```
for /r %%i in (*david*) do echo %%i|findstr /v /i /g:exclude.txt >>c:\david.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) beat me a few minutes. But I think my version is better because

- finds also hidden files and folders,
- runs `findstr` only once instead of on each found file or folder name which is faster.

The file `C:\Temp\Exclude.txt` contains the list of folders to ignore. It is important to escape `$` in the file as otherwise it will be interpreted not literal.

Example for `C:\Temp\Exclude.txt`:

```
C:\\$Recycle.bin
C:\Temp
```

The batch file contains more or less a single line:

```
@echo off
dir /A /B /S C:\*david* | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /V /G:"C:\Temp\Exclude.txt" >C:\Temp\david.log
```

As it can be read by running `dir /?` in a command prompt window, parameter `/A` results in including files and folders with any attribute which includes also hidden and system files and folders. Option `/B` means bare format and `/S` is for searching and listing also matching files and folders in all subdirectories.

`findstr /?` executed in a command prompt window outputs help of this command. `/B` means beginning of a line. `/I` means searching with ignoring case. `/V` is the most important option as it means outputting all lines NOT containing a searched string. The file with the search string is specified with `/G`.

The results are redirected to file `C:\Temp\david.log`